# Information on simperium database automatic backups

Tags: simperium

I couldn't find much information about how often Simperium will do the automatic backups of the database. Is it on a daily basis?

Answer (score 0):

Automatic backups of all data are taken regularly throughout the day. The exact frequency depends and has been changing as we evolve the architecture.